# Snowflake ODBC driver and SQL Server Polybase

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, polybase

We're currently running a POC with Snowflake and want to integrate it with our existing on premises SQL Server 2019 data warehouse. I've been playing with the standard ODBC driver provided by snowflake, and can get Polybase to connect and talk to tables in our snowflake instance, however I can't get it to play nice with date based columns:

> Msg 105083, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> 105083;The following columns in the user defined schema are incompatible with the external table schema for table 'DateTest': 'DATE1' failed to be reflected with the error: 'The detected ODBC SQL_TYPE 11 is not supported for external generic tables.'. Could not reflect the following detected external table columns: 'DATE1' failed to be reflected with the error: 'The detected ODBC SQL_TYPE 11 is not supported for external generic tables.', 'DATE2' failed to be reflected with the error: 'The detected ODBC SQL_TYPE SqlDateTime is not supported for external generic tables.', 'DATE3' failed to be reflected with the error: 'The detected ODBC SQL_TYPE SqlDateTime is not supported for external generic tables.'.

> Completion time: 2021-03-02T14:11:52.7221079+10:00

I've attempted to follow the ODBC parameter options mentioned here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html

From what I read, I would've thought this parameter would've solved it, but no luck at least from I can see: `odbc_use_standard_timestamp_columnsize`

I'm all out of ideas on what/if anything that I can do here. I have found an ODBC driver provided by CDATA that seems to work, but I suspect it is going to cost a lot of money, so would prefer to see if the standard snowflake ODBC driver will work first.

Comment: The error you posted is from Polybase I assume, is there an error in the ODBC log as well?

Comment: I can't see any errors in the ODBC log. If I connect to the database using a normal ODBC based Linked Server, it returns everything as expected. However if I connect using the same ODBC connection via Excel, any columns that are a DATE in snowflake cause an error. TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) works fine.

Comment: @Chris did You ever solve this? I have a similar issues with datetime fields on Sybase.